# ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT returning "conent:/com.android..."

Tags: android

I run an intent with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

it returns a Uri with a path like " content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document"

How do you get the correct path from this returned Uri?

Answer (score 0):

That was Uri not a  `Uri with a path like.`  you get actual file where its saved using below snippet.

```
 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();               
 String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
 Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
 String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pick any file using System File Picker:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT) //ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT (same procedure)
intent.type = "*/*"
startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
```

onActivityResult:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val file = data?.data?.let {
            getFileFromUri(requireContext().contentResolver, uri, requireContext().cacheDir)
        }
    }
}
```

Get File:

```
private fun getFileFromUri(contentResolver: ContentResolver, uri: Uri, directory: File): File {
    val file =
        File.createTempFile("suffix", "prefix", directory)
    file.outputStream().use {
        contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)?.copyTo(it)
    }

    return file
}
```

With the file, we can get the actual path to process further